# How to format HTML returned by Verify.PlayWright for better comparison

Tags: snapshot-testing, playwright-sharp, verify-tests

I am using [Verify.PlayWright](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify.HeadlessBrowsers#playwright-usage) and to take HTML element snapshots. When the compare opens, all the HTML is on one line. This makes it hard to see the differences. Is there a way to format the HTML in order to get a nicer comparison?

```
var root = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#sectionContainer .tree-root");
await Verifier.Verify(root);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Verify.AngleSharp](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify.AngleSharp). It has a feature that ppretty prints html](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify.AngleSharp#pretty-print) for comparison purposes.

- install https://nuget.org/packages/Verify.AngleSharp/
- Call `VerifyAngleSharpDiffing.Initialize()` once at assembly load time.
- use `PrettyPrintHtml` in your test:

```cs
[Test]
public Task PrettyPrintHtml()
{
    var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
    return Verifier.Verify(html)
        .UseExtension("html")
        .PrettyPrintHtml();
}
```

which will produce a verified file containing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Simon. Also thank you for the lovely tool. It is a true time saver rather than hand coding test objects for expected results.